# Is there any way to redirect URL and return status code 200

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to redirect URL and  return status code 200 in stead of status code 301,302

```
   public IActionResult OnGet(string fileId)
    {
        var url =
            @$"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}?alt=media";
        
        return Redirect(url);

    }
```

Is it possible to do it ? thanks

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not sensible.  The 200 code literally means "this request succeeded and here's the output you should display".  The signal that tells the browser to redirect is a 301 or 302.

Now, there is a slimy way to do this.  You can send a 200 result with garbage content and a "Refresh" header:

```
Refresh: 0; url="https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}?alt=media"
```

I'm not an ASP guru, but the docs suggest this should work (which you could have read as well):

```cs
{
    Response.Headers.Add( "Refresh", 
@$"0; url='https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}?alt=media'");
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, would you please tell me how to make that request in my action?

Comment: Why do you not want to do this the right way, using a 301 or 302?

Comment: It's because of my website SEO. I want to play online video in my site but video source is from another website and I want the src in <video> tag  to show my site domain not other site (source site) domain. Link of source video site is like www.video.com/film.mp4, but I  want to change it to www.example.com/film.mp4 and then put it on src of <video> tag. The only way I found it was with ` return Redirect(url);` but it shows status code 302 in browser, and it's not good for my SEO. So I confuse what should I do...

Comment: I think manipulating your status codes for the sake of SEO is utter nonsense.  Make it work the way it's designed to work.